# Javascript reverse() not working in the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reverse

I have the following webservice call which I am using to populate a dropdown menu in the UI. I am getting these records in increasing number of `createDate` by the webservice if I am not using the `reverse()` method of Array. So I decided to use it in the following manner:

```
$.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("eppn", emailID+"@abc.com");
          },
       
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/Services/getUserByDate?userid=JACK',
        type : 'GET',
 
        dataType:'json',
        success : function(data) {
                console.log("Sept 18 : Testing getUserByDate webservice");  
                console.log(data.usersList.reverse());
                $.each(data.usersList.reverse(), function (i) { 
                $("#userSetList").append('<option><a href="#" >'+data.usersList[i].title+' | '+data.usersList[i].userSetId+' | '+moment(data.usersList[i].createDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')+'</a></option>');
                            
                });
        },
        error : function(request,error)
        {
             $.growl.error({title: "Error", message: "Webservice request failed!" });
        }
});
```

And noticed the following:

```
console.log("Sept 18 : Testing getUserByDate webservice");  
    console.log(data.usersList.reverse());
```

Above code showed the items in reversed format as expected. However, when I tested the following:

```
$.each(data.usersList.reverse(), function (i) { 
    $("#userSetList").append('<option><a href="#" >'+data.usersList[i].title+' | '+data.usersList[i].userSetId+' | '+moment(data.usersList[i].createDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')+'</a></option>');
});
```

It’s not showing items in reverse order in the UI dropdown menu. Why?

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example **Minimal, Reproducible Example**

Comment: So you reverse the array in the console.log() and than you reverse() the array in the loop....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) reverses an array **in place** and then returns it.

In your code, you reverse then array when calling `console.log(data.usersList.reverse());` and then again in `$.each(data.usersList.reverse(), ...`. Since you're reversing the same array twice, it's returned to its original order.

Instead, you can call `reverse` once, and then have the subsequent call use `data.userList` directly:

```js
// data.userList is reversed in place
data.usersList.reverse();
console.log(data.userList);
$.each(data.usersList, function (i) { 
    $("#userSetList").append('<option><a href="#" >'+data.usersList[i].title+' | '+data.usersList[i].userSetId+' | '+moment(data.usersList[i].createDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')+'</a></option>');        
});
```

Comment: Thanks. In a habit to use console.log, I didn't realize that anything like that could happen.

Answer (score 2):

array.reverse() as no problem.

```js
const
  mySelect = document.getElementById('my-select')
, data =
    [ { val:'a', lib:'a_lib' }
    , { val:'b', lib:'b_lib' }
    , { val:'c', lib:'c_lib' }
    , { val:'d', lib:'d_lib' }
    ]
    
data.reverse().forEach(el=>{ mySelect.add( new Option(el.lib, el.val)) })
```

```html
<select id="my-select"></select>
```